# Plotting ambient functions with ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm using the `ambient` package in R to generate graphs. It provides a custom base plot method.

```
library(ambient)
library(dplyr)

grid <- long_grid(x = seq(0, 1, length.out = 1000),
                  y = seq(0, 1, length.out = 1000))

grid <- grid %>% 
  mutate(
    noise = fracture(gen_perlin, fbm, octaves = 4, x = x, y = y, freq_init = 5)
  )

plot(grid, noise)
```

[image]

However I'd like to plot this image using `ggplot2` and `geom_raster` instead of base plotting. I tried doing

```
ggplot(grid, aes(x = x, y = y, color = noise)) +
  geom_raster()
```

But that just produced

[image]

Any idea how I can make this with ggplot2?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wrong aesthetic: raster draws a bunch of same-size tiles, where the `color` is the border and the `fill` is the color of the tile.  You want `fill=noise` here:

```
ggplot(grid, aes(x,y, fill=noise)) + geom_raster()
```

[image]